# How to set and maintain attributes on subranges of text in NSTextView as user edits the text?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstextview, nsparagraphstyle

I'd like to have custom line wrapping behavior for subranges of text in my `NSTextView`. Specifically, I'd like lines that look like list items (start with zero or more characters of leading whitespace, then a bullet character, then a space, then a non-space character) to wrap so that lines after the first line are indented two spaces right of the bullet.

I believe I can do this by setting an `NSParagraphStyle` on the subrange of text that represents the list item with a `headIndent` calculated to be the proper distance.

Beyond that, I don't know how to proceed. Where do I hook in to `NSTextView` to set this? How do I maintain (set, update, or remove) the `NSParagraphStyle` attribute and subrange as the user edits the text? This is an `NSTextView` so the text can be edited, copy/pasted, or read in from a file.

Is there a general (and performant) method for applying and maintaining attributes to subranges of text in an `NSTextView`?